# NSLayoutConstraint gives so many warnings if i simply add scrollview in it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I have stuck at problem, in my application i am adding `UIScrollview` programatically so i am adding NSLayoutConstraint for that but when i run this output is perfect what i want but it gives me so many warning,

So please help me to removing all this warnings,

**My Code is** :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *sc=[UIScrollView new];
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:sc];
    sc.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sc);
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-5-[sc]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[sc]-5-|"
                                                          options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

  }
```

Unnecessary **warnings**:

```
  2014-02-27 15:08:26.763 TKScroller[2580:a0b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8da0df0 H:|-(10)-[UIView:0x8d95ef0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x8d93800 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8da6b10 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x8d95ef0.midX ==>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8da0df0 H:|-(10)-[UIView:0x8d95ef0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x8d93800 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-02-27 15:08:26.765 TKScroller[2580:a0b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8da15b0 V:|-(3)-[UIView:0x8d95ef0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x8d93800 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8da59d0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x8d95ef0.midY ==>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8da15b0 V:|-(3)-[UIView:0x8d95ef0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x8d93800 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-02-27 15:08:26.766 TKScroller[2580:a0b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8da1580 UIView:0x8d95ef0.trailing == UIScrollView:0x8d93800.trailing - 10>",
    "<_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint:0x8da1200 UIScrollView:0x8d93800.contentWidth{id: 128} == 0.000000>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8da6b10 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x8d95ef0.midX ==>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8da6e00 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x8d95ef0(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8da1580 UIView:0x8d95ef0.trailing == UIScrollView:0x8d93800.trailing - 10>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-02-27 15:08:26.770 TKScroller[2580:a0b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8da15e0 UIView:0x8d95ef0.bottom == UIScrollView:0x8d93800.bottom - 3>",
    "<_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint:0x8da13a0 UIScrollView:0x8d93800.contentHeight{id: 133} == 0.000000>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8da59d0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x8d95ef0.midY ==>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8da46f0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x8d95ef0(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8da15e0 UIView:0x8d95ef0.bottom == UIScrollView:0x8d93800.bottom - 3>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 2):

From the error messages it looks like you also need to do:

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

These messages:

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8da6b10 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x8d95ef0.midX ==>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8da6e00 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x8d95ef0(0)]>"
```

Lead me to believe that the parent view (self.view) is also converting autoresizing masks to constraints.

Answer (score 0):

First: try advice @Jack Cox
Second:
in line

```
 NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-5-[sc]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
```

you not say what about orientation V: or H:? try relpace this line:

```
 NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[sc]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
```

MB. your constraints array rewrite? Try it:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[sc]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[sc]-5-|" options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
```